# Distinguish error template between admin page and typical page in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to distinguish error page between admin and typical user in Spring Boot.
I have written a custom ErrorController with a mapping for /error like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = getErrorAttributes(request, true);
    model.addAttribute("status", response.getStatus());
    model.addAttribute("error", errorAttributes.get("error"));
    model.addAttribute("message", errorAttributes.get("message"));
    model.addAttribute("trace", errorAttributes.get("trace"));

    return specifyContext(request);
}
```

and in specifyContext method i need to specify which error page to show. I can see that there are some variables that i can use, like a table specialAttributes which contains an url from which error page was called (like /admin/d), but i have no idea how can i aquire this.
Is there any way to get this variable or maybe there is a simpler solution for my problem?

Comment: So you have error handler method and now you need to tell sprint boot that if some exception was thrown invoke it, right ?

Comment: yes, but with different layout for admin and diffrent for user

Comment: For example for admin layout is `app/admin/error` and for user is `app/user/error` ?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Ok. I will post answer for 4 hours

Comment: You need to use [controller advice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).